# How to delete characters at constant speed on EditText in Android during holding Backspace(or Delete) on Software Keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, backspace

Problem: At EditText on **Android** OS,

obviously when users press the **Backspace key** one time on Software keyboard like that in smartphones, only one character on the EditText is erased. But when keeping to press it for longer than a certain time, **the deleting speed increases** as time passed so that many words have gone at once.

Question:

This phenomenon makes someone uncomfortable, **so I want to find JAVA or XML solutions to delete characters at constant speed on EditText in Android during holding the Backspace(or Delete) on Software Keyboard**.

Since I have no idea where to start, there's no code I have tried. So if there is anyone who has tried and got a solution, I'd appreciate you answering my question. Thank u!

Comment: You may be able to delete just one character in every backspace presses.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn more about Android Button events/event handlers or other related events =)

- OnClickListener
- OnLongClickListener
- OnTouchListener
  the above 3 event linteners may help change the text deleting speed.